# Get snapshot information of vm PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, csv, virtual-machine, vmware, snapshot

I have written a little script which shows me some informations about virtual machines.

```
    $vsms = Get-VM 
    $erg = $vsms | Select-Object -Property @{N="VmName"; E={$_.Name}}, 
                                   @{N="Power"; E={$_.PowerState}}, 
                                   @{N="CustomTag1"; E={$_.CustomFields.Item("CustomTag1")}}, 
                                   @{N="Customtag2"; E={$_.CustomFields.Item("Customtag2")}}, 
                                   @{N="Customtag3"; E={$_.CustomFields.Item("Customtag3")}}, 
                                   @{N="ProvisionedSpaceGB"; E={[math]::Round($_.ProvisionedSpaceGB)}}, `
                                   @{N="UsedSpaceGB"; E={[math]::Round($_.UsedSpaceGB)}}, 
                                   @{N="IP Address";E={@($_.guest.IPAddress[0])}}

$erg | Sort-Object VmName | Export-Csv $outputPath -NoType
```

My Question is **how can i expand this script** to get informations about the restore points (creation time, etc...). And how can i export the result as csv so all creation times and other properties are in one cell/line for each vm? the result should be exported as csv like i already do.
It should look like this:

```
VmName | SnapshotCreationTime| ... other properties
testvm | 19:17 01.02.18, 19:17 02.02.18,... | other properties
testvm2| 19:17 08.02.18, 19:17 02.03.18,... | other properties
```

not:

```
VmName | SnapshotCreationTime| other properties (already in script)
testvm | 19:17 01.02.18,     | other properties
testvm | 19:17 02.02.18,     | other properties
testvm | 19:17 03.02.18,     | other properties
testvm2| 19:17 08.02.18,     | other properties
testvm2| 19:17 09.02.18,     | other properties
testvm2| 19:17 10.02.18,     | other properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `-Join` in your snapshotdate attribute.

Example:

```
(Get-VM "VMName" | Get-View) | %{
$Summary = "" | Select Name, HostName, State, NumCPU, MemoryMB, HDSizeKB, HDFreeSpaceKB, GuestOS, Datacenter, Folder, IP, SnapshotName, SnapshotDate
    $Summary.Name = $_.Summary.Config.Name
    $summary.HostName = $_.Summary.Guest.HostName
    $Summary.State = $_.Summary.Runtime.PowerState
    $Summary.NumCPU = $_.Summary.Config.NumCPU
    $Summary.MemoryMB = $_.Summary.Config.MemorySizeMB
    $Summary.HDSizeKB = $_.Guest.Disk.Capacity/1KB
    $Summary.HDFreeSpaceKB = $_.Guest.Disk.FreeSpace/1KB
    $Summary.GuestOS = $_.Summary.Config.GuestFullName
    $Summary.Folder = $_.Folder.Name
    $Summary.IP = $_.Summary.Guest.IPAddress
    $Summary.SnapshotName = &{$script:snaps = Get-Snapshot -VM $Summary.Name; $script:snaps.Name -join ','}
    $Summary.snapshotdate = $script:snaps.Created -join ','
    $Summary

}| Export-Csv C:\setup\Tezt.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter "|"
```

You are getting an output like:

```
"Name"|"HostName"|"State"|"NumCPU"|"MemoryMB"|"HDSizeKB"|"HDFreeSpaceKB"|"GuestOS"|"Datacenter"|"Folder"|"IP"|"SnapshotName"|"SnapshotDate"
"VMName"||"poweredOff"|"2"|"4096"|"0"|"0"|"Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (64-bit)"||||"Test Snap 00,Test snap 01"|"12/07/18 11:15:42 AM,12/07/18 11:16:04 AM"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: how do i integrate all names of VM in this script? I already have a csv with all names.

Comment: I run mine with an asterisk on the Get-VM command.
`(Get-VM * | Get-View)`

Comment: I tried this `$report = @()
foreach($vm in Get-View -ViewType Virtualmachine) {
$vms.SnapshotName = &{$script:snaps = Get-Snapshot -VM $vm.Name; $script:snaps.Name -join ','}
    $vms.snapshotdate = $script:snaps.Created -join ','
$report += $vms
}

`

and for Exporting to CSV:
`$report1 = $report.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property VMName
$report1 | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File $path -Encoding:UTF8 -Force`

Comment: i tested it and the columns "SnapshotName" and "Snapshotdate" are empty

Comment: I think you have a spelling mistake, is it $VMS or $VM?

`foreach($vm in Get-View -ViewType Virtualmachine) { 

$vm.Name

$vm.SnapshotName = &{$script:snaps = Get-Snapshot -VM $vm.Name; $script:snaps.Name -join ','} 

$vm.snapshotdate = $script:snaps.Created -join ','}`

Comment: 80% of the list is empty and i don't know why

Comment: Do you have snapshots on those machines?

Comment: yeah they all do a backup automatically

Comment: I can not help you with that, as I don't know how your infrastructure is deployed or what you have there. Is it a hosted environment? Do you have access to query those data from those machines? If you query those machines one by one with all the information do you get the snapshot data? There are many things to consider and I don't know if I can help you with the problems that you face with some machines in your datacenter.